# SVG Image asset not rending correctly inside Picker

Tags: swift, image, svg, swiftui, picker

I am running into an issue with SVG icons not resizing when used inside of a Picker.

By way of example, here is an example of using the SVG image assets in a basic list with the
`Picker` commented out ...

```swift
struct DebugView: View {
    @State var selectedType: DrugOrMedicineType = .tablet
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                //  Picker("Type", selection: $selectedType) {
                ForEach(DrugOrMedicineType.allCases, id: \.self) { t in
                    HStack {
                        Image(t.icon)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        Text(t.title)
                        
                    }.tag(t)
                    
                }
                // }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.. and this is what I see rendered ...

[image]

However, if I uncomment the `Picker` like this ...

```swift
struct DebugView: View {
    @State var selectedType: DrugOrMedicineType = .tablet
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Picker("Type", selection: $selectedType) {
                    ForEach(DrugOrMedicineType.allCases, id: \.self) { t in
                        HStack {
                            Image(t.icon)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            Text(t.title)
                            
                        }.tag(t)
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this rendered ...

[image]

and this is what it looks like when I try to select from the list of options ...

[image]

Can someone explain why the image doesn't follow the `HStack` layout and respect the `frame(...)` modifier when it appears in the `Picker`?

**NOTE** I am using XCode 14.0.1 and running on iOS 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like they change the way that the label is handled in the picker compared to iOS 15, that's why you are having troubles with the label, this is a working example, using the label modifier you can handle the label the way you want:

```
                import SwiftUI

            enum PickerItems: String {
                case item1
                case item2
            }

            struct pickerView: View {
                @State var selected: PickerItems = .item1
                var body: some View {
                    
                    Menu {
                        Picker(selection: $selected,
                               label: EmptyView(),
                               content: {
                            HStack {
                                
                                Text("OPTION 1")
                                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            } .tag(PickerItems.item1)
                            
                            HStack {
                                Text("OPTION 2")
                                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.circle.fill")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                
                            }
                            .tag(PickerItems.item2)
                            
                            
                        }).pickerStyle(.automatic)
                            .accentColor(.white)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Selected Item: \(selected.rawValue)")
                            .font(.title3)
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: If the idea is to use `Menu` then you can leave out the `Picker` entirely and just use a `Button`.  Much cleaner.  I guess `Picker` is broken in iOS 16?

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though the Picker is broken in iOS 16.  The best equivalent I could find was to use the `Menu` as was suggested by @guillermo-jiménez but leave out the `Picker` entirely.

Here is the result:

```swift
struct DebugView: View {
    @State var selectedType: DrugOrMedicineType = .tablet
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Text("Type")
                    Spacer()
                    Menu {
                        ForEach(DrugOrMedicineType.allCases, id: \.self) { t in
                            Button {
                                selectedType = t
                            } label: {
                                Label(t.title, image: t.icon)
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(selectedType.icon)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            Text(selectedType.title)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks as and item in the list ...

[image]

... and this is how it looks when you make a selection:

[image]